# Debug help : enum reg is incompatible with reg port

Tags: interface, system-verilog

In my module, I have an output port named Cmd which is of 'reg' type.

```
module ddesign (clk, rst, addr, data, Cmd);
    input          clk;
    input          rst;
    input [31:0]   addr;
    input [31:0]   data;
   ... 
    output reg [2:0]   Cmd; // this is the signal concerned
   ...
    always @(posedge clk) begin
        if (rst == 0) begin
            Cmd = IDLE; // I wanted to drive enum values 
        end
        else begin
            Cmd = WR;
            ...
         end
     end 

endmodule;
```

I have also defined the signal Cmd using typedef as shown below in another file.

```
typedef enum logic [2:0] {
    IDLE,
    WR,
    RD,
    RDX,
    RDL,
    WRN,
    WRC,
    BROADCAST
} Cmd_t;
```

The interface is defined like this

```
Interface intf (input clk);
   Cmd_t Cmd;
   ...
endinterface
```

In top file where I instantiated the module,

```
module top;
     ...
    intf vif(clk); // interface instantiation

     ddesign dut(
        ...
     .Cmd(vif.Cmd), // the module port and interface are connected like this, but here is the incompatibility problem 
        ...
      );
endmodule
```

so I get the following error:

## ** Error: (vsim-3906) F:/folder1/project1/DV/top/top.sv(79): Connection type 'file_list_svh_unit.enum reg[2:0] ' is incompatible with 'reg[2:0]' for  port (Cmd).

How to resolve this error, provided I can drive enum type values on Cmd signal in my design module?

Comment: You could do with constructing an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I did so on [EDA Playground](https://www.edaplayground.com/x/6Fz9) and found no error. I also tried it on Questa and found no error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `Cmd` is an output port of your design, you are trying to make an assignment from variable that is not an `enum` to another variable that is an `enum`. That is not legal without a cast. And SystemVerilog has no way to specify a cast to the target (or lvalue) of an assignment.

So you need to do one of two things:

- Declare your Cmd port using the Cmd_t type
- Connect your Cmd port to a compatible variable type in your interface, and use a continuous assignment to cast it to the Cmd_t type.

Answer (score 1):

Normally it is not legal to assign an `enum` to a valued not of the same type without casting. However, there is a workaround by specifying the bit range on the enum. It works a the simulators I tried. I'm not sure if this workaround is an intended or unintended feature of the simulator or the LRM itself.

```
ddesign dut(
  .Cmd(vif.Cmd[2:0]), 
  .* );
```